# Local expansion of a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

I've been staring at this local expansion, from a paper, of a multivariate polynomial but I can't quite understand it. It goes as follows:

$\mathcal{C}$: Field of Complex numbers

Let $x=(x_1, x_2...,x_n) \in \mathcal{C}^n$ and $f$ be a univariate polynomial.
For any $\bar{x} \in \mathcal{C}^n$
The authors claim, for any $y, \bar{y} \in \mathcal{C}$:

(1) $f(y) = f(\bar{y}) + (y - \bar{y}) g(y)$

Which I can certainly believe. For the vectors $x, \bar{x} \in \mathcal{C}^n$:

(2) $f(x) = f(\bar{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x_i}) g_i(x)$
Where $f$ is n-variate polyinomial, (I guess $f: \mathcal{C}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$)

I suppose (2) is derived from (1), though I am not sure how and I would appreciate it if anyone knows where I can find something similar to help me understand it.

The authors then go further and

(3) $f(x) = f(\bar{x}) + (x - \bar{x})^TG(x)$

Which seems to me like (2), though $G(x)$ is not clear to me anymore. For this to
be equivalent to (2), I guess $G(x)$ must refer to a column vector $(g_1(x),  g_2(x) ... g_n(x))$ However, I am not sure.

Finally, the most confusing is this part:
Then they replace the scalar $x_i$ by a matrix variable $X_i$ and:
(4) $f(X) = f(\bar{X}) + \sum_{i=1}^n Trace(X_i - \bar{X_i}) G_i(X))$  $\forall X$

Where each $G_i$ is a matrix whose entries are polynomials dependent on the entries of $\bar{X}$ and the coefficients of $f$ only.
The previous expansions I may be shakey on, but at least I know what they are saying... This one I have no idea. Unfortunately the authors don't make it clear what how $X$ and $X_i$ relate.. Or how $x_i$ and $X_i$ relate if at all. Is each $X_i$ simply $x_i \cdot I$?

I suppose the authors must assume this is familiar to the reader and so skipped over some of the details. If you have seen something like this, please let me know where to look for it so I can decipher this expansion.

Comment: Ref: Razaviyayn, Lyubeznik and Luo:
"on the degrees of freedom achievable through interference alignment in a mimo interference channel"
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.0992.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, they use $\bar x$ to mean something other than conjugate, despite  $x$ being a complex number? How quaint.

One can prove both (1) and (2) by writing out the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) for $f$ centered at point $a$ (formerly known as $\bar x$). The series terminates, eliminating all issues of convergence. Each of its terms, except for $f(a)$, is divisible by at least one of the monomials $x_j-a_j$.

(3) is indeed nothing but (2) rewritten in vector notation. The elements of $\mathbb C^n$ are understood as column vectors, so $(x-a)^T$ is a row vector. Multiplying it by the column of $g_1,\dots,g_n$ produces the same sum as in (2).

The transition to (4) is easy once you get used to a certain trick in linear algebra. A square matrix  of size $n\times n$ can also be seen as a vector of size $n^2$, for example by stacking the columns on top of each other. For vectors we have the notion of scalar (inner, dot...) product. Can the inner product of  two matrices-turned-into-vectors be expressed in terms of the matrices themselves? Yes: it is 
$$\langle A,B\rangle = \sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}b_{ij} = \operatorname{trace}A^TB  = \operatorname{trace}A  B^T \tag{I}$$
(*real* matrices here; I don't want to mess with conjugation.) One proves (1) by actually multiplying the matrices and summing the diagonal entries of the product: the sum is $\sum_{ij}a_{ij}b_{ij}$.

Now I regret saying "inner product" because this is not really what appears in (4): there is no conjugation there. We just apply (3) to $X$ written as a stacked vector, and then rewrite the sum $\sum (x_j-a_j)g_j(x)$ in matrix form using (I).

---

Remark: when asking questions about the content of a paper, you should *give a reference to the paper* (and a link if possible).

Comment: Thanks! I'd never seen this Taylor Series before. Beautiful